# How do I make an array in onValue() function freely usable outside of the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first application and I'm currently using a real-time database (Firebase). I'm trying to get a value from `timeArray[]` and have it shown in `timeInput.innerHTML` when I click the "Save" Button, but then I got an error saying `timeArray[]` is not defined.

```
onValue(qualTime, function(snapshot) {
  let timeArray = Object.values(snapshot.val());
});

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("timeInput").innerHTML = timeArray[0];
});
```

I also tried putting the `saveButton.addEventListener()` in the `onValue()` but that got the console to throw at me a bunch of errors and the HTML app itself prints out undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the issue is related to the `variable` scope. Variables defined with `let` have block scope. Hence, `timeArray` will not be accessible outside of the `onValue` function.

To get rid from this issue, you have to define the `timeArray` in a scope where it can be accessible from both places (`onValue` function and inside `click` event).

```
let timeArray;

onValue(qualTime, function(snapshot) {
  timeArray = Object.values(snapshot.val());
});

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (timeArray && timeArray.length) {
    document.getElementById("timeInput").innerHTML = timeArray[0];
  }
});
```